# How to get updated IP address mailed to me in DNSExit?

Tags: cron, ip-address

I'm using DNSExit on my Ubuntu server (Natty 11.04) and have installed the [ipUpdate rpm file](http://dnsexit.com/Direct.sv?cmd=userIpClients) and did an apt-get install for chkconfig to enable the ipUpdate.

I'd like to get an email whenever the IP address changes, so that I can SSH into the box using PuTTY (because I can't unless I know the current IP address).

The current IP address is stored in `/tmp/dnsexit-ip.txt`, and I'd like to, whenever that file changes, to mail the contents of that file and the contents of `/var/log/dnsexit.log` (which contains a history of the IP changes) to my email address.

How can I accomplish this task?  I'm thinking that a cronjob will be the solution, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Prerequisites

Install **sendEmail**. It's a lightweight, command line SMTP email client. We'll use it to send emails from a script, using a Gmail account.

```
sudo apt-get install sendemail libio-socket-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
```

### Create the script

Create a file named "*ip-notify.sh*" somewhere, for example in a "*Scripts*" directory in your home folder; make it executable, and open it up for editing.

```
mkdir -p ~/Scripts && touch ~/Scripts/ip-notify.sh && chmod a+x ~/Scripts/ip-notify.sh && gedit ~/Scripts/ip-notify.sh
```

Insert the following text in the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Modify the following values!

  SENDERNAME="Computer" # This is the name that will show in the 'From' field. Purely esthetic.
  RECIPIENTNAME="Your Name" # This is the name that will show in the 'To' field. Also purely esthetic.
  GMAILADDRESS="someemail@gmail.com" # This is your Gmail address.
  GMAILUSER="someemail" # This is your Gmail username, without the '@gmail.com' part.
  GMAILPASS="password" # This is your Gmail password.

# You can stop modifying here

DIR=/tmp/
CURIP=dnsexit-ip.txt
IPLOG=/var/log/dnsexit.log
SMTPSERVER="smtp.gmail.com:587"

if [[ $(find $DIR -mmin -2 -name $CURIP) ]];
then
        echo "$CURIP has been modified in the last two minutes."
        # Send an email
        sendemail -u "IP Address" -m "IP address has changed!" -f "$SENDERNAME <$GMAILADDRESS>" -t "$RECIPIENTNAME <$GMAILADDRESS>" -s $SMTPSERVER -xu $GMAILUSER -xp $GMAILPASS -a $DIR$CURIP $IPLOG
fi
```

Once that's done, save and close the file.

### Run the script periodically

We'll run this script every two minutes. Open up your crontab.

```
crontab -e
```

Add the following line to the bottom of the file:

```
*/2 * * * * bash ~/Scripts/ip-notify.sh
```

### You're done!

If all goes well, you should now get email updates when the IP address of your machine changes.

Comment: Thank you @SirCharlo, I will give it a try and test with some mock files.  Questions: 1. How to know what to put for the SenderAddress, and 2. What to set for the SmtpServer?

Comment: Good point. I modified my answer to use Gmail as the outgoing server; all you need is a Gmail account.

Comment: A few fixes for your answer @SirCharlo: in the if statement, we've got some unused `$EMAILADDRESS` variables.  To fix the first one, I added a declaration at the top, and for the second one, I changed it to `$GMAILADDRESS`.  Now, I'm getting another error: `SMTP-AUTH: Authentication to smtp.gmail.com:587 failed.`  Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed my mistake. The error you get means that either the GMAILUSER or the GMAILPASS variable is incorrect. Make sure that the username you specify is the first part of your email address (everything before the "@" sign). Make sure your password is correct, also. If that doesn't work, try replacing `SMTPSERVER="smtp.gmail.com:587"` with `SMTPSERVER="smtp.gmail.com"`.

Comment: You were correct!  The email address was wrong -- I fixed it and it works.  Question: Why did you decide to go the route where the gmail account sends the mail to itself, and not the way before where the server actually sends the mail?

Comment: Because that would have involved setting up an SMTP server on your Ubuntu machine, then relaying mail through that server to the email address of your choice. However, it's much simpler to use an existing server if we can, like Google's. It's a lot less hassle and, in your case, it seemed pretty likely to fit your needs anyway. Installing and setting up a mail server seemed like slight overkill.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mail installed (I use postfix ... i.e. sudo apt-get install postfix) you can run a bash script in cron every 5 minutes.

The script uses 'stat' to check if the file changed in the last five minutes (300 seconds) if so the $diff variable will equal 1.

Some thing like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
filemtime=`stat -c %Y /tmp/dnsexit-ip.txt`
currtime=`date +%s`
diff=$(( (currtime - filemtime) / 300 ))
x=1

if [ $diff -eq  $x ]
  then
    SUBJECT="DCHP CHANGE"
    EMAIL="youremail@example.com"
    EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/emailmessage.txt"

    echo "Contents of dnsexit-ip.txt" >$EMAILMESSAGE
    cat /tmp/dnsexit-ip.txt >> $EMAILMESSAGE
    echo "Contents of dnsexit.log" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
    cat /var/log/dnsexit.log >> $EMAILMESSAGE

    sudo /usr/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE
 fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @paradrupal.  I received a message in /var/mail/<username> with an error: `/home/<username>/ip-stat.sh: line 7: [: missing \`]'`.  How to fix this?

Comment: `if [ $diff -eq  $x ]` this just says that if $diff is equal to 1 send the mail. Please check your syntax.

Comment: I'm currently getting this error: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`.

Comment: Sorry holiday weekend ... What mail program are you using? You may not need to use sudo. Can you sudo from the command line? Are you a privileged user?

Comment: Both Postfix and SendEmail are installed.  My user account is an admin and can sudo.